# F# Pattern Matching on Generic Parameter

Tags: generics, f#, pattern-matching

I have a strange one here. I am wanting to match on the type of the generic parameter. Here is what I have so far:

```
open System.Reflection

type Chicken = {
    Size : decimal
    Name : string
}

let silly<'T> x =
    match type<'T> with
    | typeof<Chicken> -> printfn "%A" x
    | _ -> printfn "Didn't match type"
    enter code here
```

I am wanting the `silly<'T>` function to take a generic parameter and to then match on the type in the function to determine the output. Right now I get a compiler error about incorrect indentation. I'm pretty sure the indentation is fine but there is something about what I am doing the compiler simply does not like. Thoughts? I have a brute force workaround but this approach would be much simpler.

Comment: Why do you need to match on `System.Type` instead of `match box arg with :? Chicken ...`? Boxing is necessary, but you can still constrain `arg` to `'T`.

Comment: @kaefer boxing is also free if the argument is known to be a reference type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I've always done, not sure that it's "the best" but it works and makes sense to my team and I.

```
let silly<'T> x =
  match typeof<'T> with
  | t when t = typeof<TypeA>  -> TypeASpecificFunction x
  | t when t = typeof<TypeB>  -> TypeBSpecificFunction x
  | t when t = typeof<TypeC>  -> TypeCSpecificFunction x
  | _                         -> printfn "Didn't match type"
```

It requires a generic function which you have, this approach wouldn't work on typeof< x > directly, you have to do typeof<'T>.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
let silly x =
    match box x with 
    | :? Chicken as chicken -> printfn "is a  chicken = %s %A" chicken.Name chicken.Size
    | :? string  as txt     -> printfn "is a  string  = '%s'"  txt
    | :? int     as n       -> printfn "is an int     = %d"    n
    | _                     -> printfn "Didn't match type"
```

Call it like this:

```
silly "Hello"
silly 7
silly { Name = "Claudius" ; Size = 10m }

// is a  string  = 'Hello'
// is an int     = 7
// is a  chicken = Claudius 10M
```

Comment: This seems a much more straightforward approach than the accepted answer.

Comment: why does this require boxing? curious

Comment: The type test operator `:?`  works on subtypes. Since `x` is generic the compiler cannot determine its subtypes. `box` casts `x` into an `obj` (is equivalent to using `x :> obj`), everything is a subtype of `obj`. Otherwise you get the error message: `type test from type
    'a    
 to 
    Chicken    
involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Runtime type tests are not allowed on some types. Further type annotations are needed.`